# How do I avoid multiple simultaneous focus in PySide?

Tags: python, focus, pyside

I have a `QDialog` that has multiple `QLineEdit` and `QPushButton` widgets. PySide highlights both, the first `QLineEdit` and the first `QPushButton`.

How can I make it focus on one thing at a time?

I'd like to be able to tab to the `QPushButton`. So, turning off focus isn't what I want, because that stopped me from being able to tab into the button.

Here's an image of the problem:

[image: A screenshot]

And here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *


class UI(object):
    def setupUi(self, SessionInfo):
        SessionInfo.setWindowTitle("Session Info")
#       SessionInfo.resize(313, 159)
        self.sessionLabel = QLabel(SessionInfo)
        self.sessionLabel.setText("Session information:")
        self.sessionId = QLineEdit(SessionInfo)
        self.presetsLabel = QLabel(SessionInfo)
        self.presetsLabel.setText("Presets:")
        self.presetsButton = QPushButton(SessionInfo)
        self.presetsButton.setText("Choose presets file")
        self.saveButton = QPushButton(SessionInfo)
        self.saveButton.setText("Begin session")
        self.saveButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        spacerItem = QSpacerItem(40, 20,
                                 QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                 QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(SessionInfo)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.sessionLabel,   0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.sessionId,      0, 1, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.presetsLabel,   1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.presetsButton,  1, 1, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem,            2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.saveButton,     2, 2, 1, 1)


def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QDialog()
    sessionInfo = UI()
    sessionInfo.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm zooming in on default() and autoDefault() which is improving things a bit, but I still don't have the behavior I want yet. I want it to initially highlight nothing except the first LineEdit, but as I tab to a button, it should move the highlighting accordingly to that button. Turning off defaults everywhere resulted in the correct initial condition but then no buttons highlighted when tabbed to.

Comment: The focus style of button can be assigned. All you have to do is set your own focus style after removing the default button setting of a dialog. Please see my answer. @Ubuntourist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot use a `QDialog` for that because it always wants to have exactly one default button, even right from the beginning. `QWidget` instead is more nice but doesn't set the default property of its button when they get focus. However, you can do that by yourself overriding `focusInEvent`and `focusOutEvent` in your custom buttons.

Example:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *

class FocusButton(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.setDefault(True)
        QPushButton.focusInEvent(self, event)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.setDefault(False)
        QPushButton.focusOutEvent(self, event)

app = QApplication([])

dlg = QWidget()

label1 = QLabel("Label one")
label2 = QLabel("Label two")

edit1 = QLineEdit(dlg)

button1 = FocusButton("Button one")
button2 = FocusButton("Button two")

spacerItem = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

gridLayout = QGridLayout(dlg)
gridLayout.addWidget(label1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
gridLayout.addWidget(edit1, 0, 1, 1, 2)
gridLayout.addWidget(label2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
gridLayout.addWidget(button1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 0, 1, 2)
gridLayout.addWidget(button2, 2, 2, 1, 1)

dlg.show()
app.exec_()
```

And the buttons are not highlighted initially, only if they get the focus.

[image]